# what is a single word to indicate bringing something up to currency?

Tags: money

looking to bring an aged computer systems up to latest version and want a single word to represent this action.
This will form the banner line for a 3 phase strategy is, Stablise, bring up to currency, innovate.

Answer (score 4):

The usual word is "update", meaning, with more words, to bring up to date. See https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/update.